# Compare directory contents to database column in Joomla

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I have a directory with images and I need to check a specific column of a table in my joomla database to see which files exist in the directory but not in the database and delete them.

What I've tried so far has not worked at all

my code is this

```
$dir = 'directory/of/files';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT image FROM #__tablename WHERE something LIKE 'something else'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result =  $db->loadResultArray();

foreach ( $files1 as $file ) {

if (stripos($result, $file) === false) {echo 'file '.$file.' does not exist in      database '; unlink($dir.$file);}
else {echo 'file '.$file.' exists in db ';}

}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I finally managed to write and do what I need

```
$preImagePath = 'some/path/';
$fullImagePath = $params->get('extra1');//more of the path

$value = $params->get('extra3');

$initfile = scandir($preImagePath.$fullImagePath);
$files1 = array_diff($initfile, array('.', '..'));

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT image FROM #__table WHERE column LIKE '".$value."'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results =  $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
$imagearray .= $result->image.' ';
}

foreach ( $files1 as $file ) {
if (strpos($imagearray, $fullImagePath.$file) === false) {             unlink($preImagePath.$fullImagePath.$file); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that in `if(stripos($result, $file))`, $result is an array, not a string. Turn on error reporting in the Joomla Configuration to see this. You should be seeing a message like:

```
Warning: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

However, I recommend the following change as it is a bit cleaner:

```
$dir = 'directory/of/files';
$files1 = scandir($dir);

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT image FROM #__tablename WHERE something LIKE 'something else'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result =  $db->loadResultArray();

$diff = array_diff($files1, $result);
// print_r($diff);die;

foreach ( $diff as $file ) {
    unlink($dir.$file);
}
```

Uncomment the `print_r` first to check it is what you want.

Comment: that looks like it's gonna do the trick. I'm redownloading the images at the moment because my previous attempts ended up deleting all of the files. Will comment with results asap. Thank you so much

Comment: it throws an error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: the error is on the $diff = array_diff($files1, $result); line